# How to allow react semantic ui dropdowns that are repeating display different values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have a method in my `React Component` where based on a number value I display a row of components. The problem I am having is when I select on component the same value is selected in that component for a different row.

Here is my code

```js
showSkillsModalCategoryUI = () => {
    const {
      startDate,
      endDate,
      errors,
      reviewerSearch: {
        contentAreaSkills,
        otherSkills,
        numOfDaysForReview,
        numOfReviewerPositions,
      },
    } = this.state;

    var data = [];
    var length = numOfReviewerPositions; // user defined length

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      data.push('undefined');
    }

    const row = data.map((position, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <div className="ui grid">
            <div className="three wide column">
              <Form.Field
                name="numOfDaysForReview"
                label=""
                placeholder="# of days"
                value={numOfDaysForReview}
                onChange={this.handleSearchFilterChange}
                category={'numOfDaysForReview'}
                control={AmsLookupDropdown}
                fluid
                search
                selection
              />
            </div>
            <div className="four wide column">
              <Form.Group>
                <Form.Field
                  name="startDate"
                  control={DatePicker}
                  placeholder="Please select start Date"
                  isClearable={true}
                  selected={startDate && startDate}
                  selectsStart
                  minDate={moment()}
                  startDate={startDate && startDate}
                  onChange={this.handleStartDateChange}
                />
                <Form.Field
                  name="endDate"
                  control={DatePicker}
                  placeholder="Please select end date"
                  isClearable={true}
                  selected={endDate && endDate}
                  selectsEnd
                  startDate={startDate && startDate}
                  minDate={startDate && startDate}
                  endDate={endDate}
                  onChange={this.handleEndDateChange}
                />
              </Form.Group>
            </div>
            <div className="three wide column">
              <Form.Field
                name="languageSkills"
                label=""
                placeholder="Language"
                defaultValue={'English'}
                onChange={(e, { value }) =>
                  this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    reviewerSearch: {
                      ...this.state.reviewerSearch,
                      languageSkills: value,
                    },
                  })
                }
                category={'languages'}
                control={AmsLookupDropdown}
                fluid
                multiple
                search
                selection
              />
            </div>
            <div className="three wide column">
              <Form.Field
                error={!!errors.contentAreaSkills}
                name="contentAreaSkills"
                label=""
                placeholder="Content"
                value={contentAreaSkills}
                onChange={(e, { value }) =>
                  this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    reviewerSearch: {
                      ...this.state.reviewerSearch,
                      contentAreaSkills: value,
                    },
                  })
                }
                category={'contentAreaSkills'}
                control={AmsLookupDropdown}
                fluid
                multiple
                search
                selection
              />
            </div>
            <div className="three wide column">
              <Form.Field
                name="otherSkills"
                width={14}
                label=""
                placeholder="Other"
                value={otherSkills}
                onChange={(e, { value }) =>
                  this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    reviewerSearch: {
                      ...this.state.reviewerSearch,
                      otherSkills: value,
                    },
                  })
                }
                category={'otherSkills'}
                control={AmsLookupDropdown}
                fluid
                multiple
                search
                selection
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return row;
  };
```

For instance if I have 3 rows of these components and I select a language like english. All the language controls in each row will have english and if I try and change them on each row all change. So I cannot select an individual value.

Comment: Can you please replace your for loop with this ? Array.from({length: numOfReviewerPositions}, (v, k) => k+1); , this is not gonna help you fix your problem by the way

Comment: @ZeRubeus thank you for the suggestion. But I am looking for the relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

All your rows use the same state, you need to create an array of states that takes the index of your map, so each row have an independent state, exemple:

```
 onChange={(e, { value }) =>
      this.setState({
      ...this.state,
     ['stateOfRow' + index]: theState ....
   )
 }
```

You get the idea, your rows doesn't have to share the same state if each one set its own.

To apply this to your case, the code will look like this:

The state:

```
  const {
    startDate,
    endDate,
    errors,
    rowState // <== this is an Array []
  } = this.state;
```

Portion if the code:

```
    <Form.Field
      name="otherSkills"
      width={14}
      label=""
      placeholder="Other"
      value={rowState[index].reviewerSearch.otherSkills}
      onChange={(e, { value }) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          rowState: [
           ...prevState,
           [rowState[index]],
           {
             reviewerSearch: {
              ...prevState.rowState[index].reviewerSearch,
              otherSkills: value,
            },
           },
          ],
        }));
      }}
      category={"otherSkills"}
      control={AmsLookupDropdown}
      fluid
      multiple
      search
      selection
    />
```

Comment: Can you provide an example for one of the above controls?

Comment: Gemme me a minute

Comment: What happened to the on change event?

Comment: I am getting syntax errors with this. `...prevState.rowState[index].reviewerSearch,` indes is throwing a syntax error

Comment: It's a bracket missing somewhere

Comment: I am getting an error for `value={rowState[index].reviewerSearch.otherSkills}` the error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: I am also getting that same error for the beginning of the array in setState `rowState: [`